# gdaladdo still very slow on large TIFF

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdaladdo, map-overviews, bigtiff

I'm trying to build internal overviews on a big GeoTIFF using gdaladdo and it is way too slow.

From what I could find out it is a known problem ([#1442](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1442)) that has been solved in [May last year](https://github.com/rouault/gdal/commit/f8250e8892acd784caa635d1efffc098f9709ff6)

However in my case it is still excruciating slow. I'm wondering what I could do wrong (I use GDAL 3.0.2 released on 28/10/2019).

I tried to generate 1 level of external overview with the following command. It lasted 68 min which is fine

`P:\>gdaladdo -ro -r average --config BIGTIFF_OVERVIEW YES --config INTERLEAVE_OVERVIEW PIXEL --config GDAL_TIFF_INTERNAL_MASK YES --config PHOTOMETRIC_OVERVIEW YCBCR --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW JPEG --config JPEG_QUALITY_OVERVIEW 85 "C:\superorto_ext.tif" 2`

With the exact same command on the same file but with internal overviews (without the -ro switch)  it lasted 6 hours and 50 min which is not so fine

`P:\>gdaladdo -r average --config BIGTIFF_OVERVIEW YES --config INTERLEAVE_OVERVIEW PIXEL --config GDAL_TIFF_INTERNAL_MASK YES --config PHOTOMETRIC_OVERVIEW YCBCR --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW JPEG --config JPEG_QUALITY_OVERVIEW 85 "C:\superorto_ext.tif" 2`

Comment: Some information on the code you are running as well as info on the dataset used might help users provide an answer.

Comment: Looks like that PR was only merged into the master branch and not backported to the 3x series.  Find a recent dev. build or build from source.

Comment: have you tried building a COG tif from your tif + external overview ? gdal_translate input.tif cog.tiff -co COPY_SRC_OVERVIEWS=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW -co TILED=YES -co BIGTIFF=YES

Comment: Thanks user2856. It is as you said : the feature will be available only in the 3.1.0 version. I ended up doing as you suggested radouxju and build external everview one level at a time and then merge them all together using the COPY_SRC_OVERVIEWS=YES command. It took a bit of brainstorming but worked out well in the end :-)

Answer (score 1):

I got the information from [here](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/2147#issuecomment-570547021) that gdal 3.0.2 does not yet include the "fast overviews for big TIFF" feature It will be included in the 3.1 version